# How big is the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

Does it contain the whole universe (whether obeying physics laws as we know it or not)? Or, is it just limited to solar system & fake EM radiations coming from outside?

I was just wondering how machines would manage to process detailed simulations of infinite astronomical bodies (which looks impossible due to limited knowledge of universe, too).. and, what would happen if Neo started to explore the universe with warp speed.

I have seen all three movies and Animatrix, but without any luck around this question. So, I am looking for answers from novels, comics etc.

Comment: How would the whole mysterious universe "screw Einstein and Hawkings[sic]"?

Comment: who said physicist of the like of  Einstein and Hawkings were humans plugged to the matrix?

Comment: @phantom42 "God. He doesn't play dice." | "Not only does God play dice, but... he sometimes throws them where they cannot be seen." | "All the evidence shows that God was actually quite a gambler, and the universe is a great casino, where dice are thrown, and roulette wheels spin on every occasion." | "God doesn't exist."

Comment: OK, you've quoted Einstein. This still doesn't explain how Einstein and Hawking are "screwed".

Comment: As far as the past few years go... the matrix wouldn't have to be very large at all. Just large enough to support a few "space-rafts". Perhaps that's why time re-winded in the matrix, to a time when space-travel is virtually non-existant. No one knows how the matrix is "rendered", if it's even based on an established map at all.

Comment: @phantom42 You shouldn't be asking this. We always get contradictory theories and we always introduce dark energy and dark matter type magical things...

Comment: What's up with the downvotes? It's a perfectly valid option to have built the Matrix simulation with physics laws being violated in the simulation on cosmological scale (the way they are clearly violated on human scale by Neo). +1.

Comment: Since there where only a handful of comics and no novels, outside of what was detailed in the MMORPG The Matrix Online, all information would be speculative.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question but I don't think it's very well thought out and @SachinShekhar has asked several questions that are all basically the same without apparently doing any research.

Comment: After reconsidering I've voted to close this as I think it's not constructive. There's just too little information to base a premise on which means its too likely to be debated.

Comment: @APaleShadow With the last sentence, I have already limited the domain.. Why do you think it can open a debate?

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment

Comment: Surely, no more than 256Kb?

Answer (score 22):

During Morpheus' interrogation Agent Smith stated that the Matrix had been redesigned to match the peak of human civilization, which turned out to be circa 1999.  Albert Einstein died in 1955, and Hawking had made his mark on physics by 1975.  So, assuming Smith wasn't lying, Einstein and Hawking were working from real data collected from the real universe.  Also, we certainly didn't have strong AI in 1999 so the Matrix and subsequent enslavement of humanity came later, much later.

As for the Matrix simulation itself, astronomical data is easily faked, as is data from atom smashers and other electronic proxies humans use to study nature.  The whole universe doesn't have to be simulated, only the parts humans and their instruments are observing at any given time.  Since all the astronomers and telescopes and neutrino detectors are in Matrix, this should be an easy problem for a civilization that can sustain a realistic non-stop VR MMORPG for six billion people.

Answer (score 10):

Note that there's only *one* city in The Matrix, it doesn't even have a name it just '[The City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_City_%28The_Matrix%29)'. From the wikipedia article:

> In The Matrix Reloaded, Neo is transported to a remote mountainous area resembling the Alps or the Himalayas (supposedly the location of the Merovingian's mansion), from which he has to fly "500 miles due south" in order to return to the City.

If we assume that the Merovingian would place his mansion near the outer bounds, and that it is a roughly circular shape, then the minimum size of the virtual reality is approximately 1000 miles across.

While there is mention of other locations in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_City_%28The_Matrix%29#Locations_outside_of_Mega_City) there is nothing in the movies directly states (as opposed to implying) there is anything else other than the city and it's environs.

Comment: Nice one, but if you can recall the beginning of the movie, Neo as Mr. Anderson worked at one of the best software companies of the WORLD.

Comment: @Sachin this doesn`t invalidate the point. If the city is all there is, then the city is the world. AQuite a few arguments are based on our knowledge. You must consider that the knowledge of the people in the Matrix may be very different.

Comment: @SachinShekhar as flq says that's hardly a decent argument

Comment: In the news articles in the first movie that appear on Neo's monitor, Heathrow airport is mentioned. So its fair to say that London exists. Therfore England exists, and seeing as the movie is set no where near england, the whole world exists

Comment: @harmingcola: Just because a place is mentioned, everyone has heard of it, and some people even think they've been there doesn't mean it exists. Shell Beach from Dark City would be a relevant example.

Comment: Yes, the world is just a city, which is called ... Coruscant ;-)

Comment: There are also multiple cities (including Tokyo) seen in the Animatrix.

Comment: Scenes from all over the world are also seen on the screens in the Architect's room, in the part where he says "the relevant issue is whether or not you are ready to accept the responsibility for the death of every human being in this world"--see 5:20 in [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wdKlWXyUkc).

Answer (score 5):

The only places visited in the Matrix are sites within the Mega City and outlying areas.  However, it can be assumed that there are several other cities or even countries ourside of the Mega City.  When Neo does a search on Morpheus early in the movie, it turns up a search result "Morpheus eludes police at Heathrow Airport".  This seems to suggest that London is simulated inside of the Matrix as well as the Mega City.  Also, when the Agents do a background check on Neo during the interrogation, it shows his birthplace as "Lower Downtown, Capital City", suggesting that there is at least another city inside of the Matrix, which would be called Capital City.  There are counter-arguments for this, though.  Some say that Capital City might simply be the official name for the Mega City.

Comment: This ignores the other locations seen in the Animatrix (also considered fully canon).

Answer (score 4):

Something that was never mentioned but could easily be the case is that the Matrix may be quite poor with respect to the richness of the simulation of the Universe.

Considering that humans are born and raised in the Matrix, the knowledge of reality could easily be faked such that there are hardly any stars, let alone galaxies out there. For all we know, even the moon may be missing in the Matrix. Who would be there to question this?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of size - even virtual size - it's incorrect to speak of any kind of scale.  The Matrix is as "big" as each individual in it needs it to be.  If you're on your own in a room, the Matrix is as "big" as that room so far as you're concerned.  Why would the machines waste processing power creating an entire world outside of that room in your perception of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that... Mind it, outsiders' avatars were able to interact with avatars of insiders.

Comment: Actually it very well could work like that.  There would be no reason to render, say a deserted island in the middle of the ocean, if there wasn't anyone interacting with it.  This would save on processing power.

Comment: @Monty129 The problem is: Everything is dynamic. So, to resume any simulation, there's need of heavy processing to predict the state after certain duration. It wasn't going to save processing power..

Comment: If you look at a typical persistent-world game engine, this is actually exactly what they do.  The Matrix would be a surprisingly low number of orders of magnitude up from that, at least so far as simulation of the world is concerned.

Comment: @Monty129: Sounds like the question 'Does a falling tree in the forest make noise when there is no one to hear it?'

Comment: That's more philosophical than needs to be @GauravAgarwal  This is more of a technical statement.  There would be no need to divert processing power to rendering something that didn't need to be rendered.

Comment: @mh01 I like your point about rendering only what can be seen.  But I disagree with your assertion that it is "incorrect to speak of scale".  Unless the Matrix will randomly generate a map for you and remember it for later if you go too far in one direction, then scale does matter.  I've personally assumed all along that the Matrix simulates the entire surface of the Earth.  Though, like you said, it only *renders* what is currently being observed.

Comment: It's late to the party but several clues are given in Reloaded. 1) The intro clock parts scene - the Matrix is rendered down to the atom using fractals. Which mind you is internal clock parts to punch in/out at the bldg. 2) The Architect is only interested in building things bound by the parameters of perfection.

So everything is rendered, no culling what-so-ever. Why? Because we're more perfect than you, and you humans, are the bovine of the planet. Moo baby. ;)