# Are there people in outer space in the real world?

Tags: the-matrix

Is there any indication in canon material (perhaps the comics?) that people were in space during the machine uprising or when the first iteration of the matrix was created?

I'm **not** asking [if a person can go into outer space in the Matrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31566/how-big-is-the-matrix), but in the real world, given the approximate year of 2199 by Morpheus, it doesn't seem too far-fetched that living on a space station or ship would be implausible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going with a qualified **"no"**. [Operation Dark Storm](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Operation_Dark_Storm) filled the sky with molecular replicators capable of "drain[ing] the life" out of any electrical device passing through it.

> *[The molecular replicators immediately drain the life from the Sentinels and they fall dead tearing through the clouds that cling to them momentarily like shredded pieces of parachute, before letting them fall away.]*
>
> *[The Logos is engulfed by a ball of lightning as it is attacked by the sky. It shakes violently, every light blowing out, until the ship dies]*
>
> <sub><sup>Matrix Revolutions: Screenplay</sup></sub>

Given that trying to get into space without electrics is impossible and returning to Earth from space without electrics is *almost* impossible, I can't imagine that the space-faring nations of the world would send their astronauts to their deaths for no discernible benefit. They would have returned them to Earth before burning the sky.

Comment: Some people believe that the sidereal universe is populated with "space aliens" but I suppose but I suppose that in this question "people" means "Earth people".

Comment: @user14111 - A space alien appears in the [Matrix story Goliath](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Goliath), but it's a gigantic space squid

Comment: Is it an *intelligent* squid? Intelligent beings are 'people' even if they look like squids.

Comment: @user14111 - It's aggressive and adaptive. There's no specific signs of it being sentient other than attempting to murder someone trying to kill it but it also drops rocks (from space) onto a Matrix tower, which strongly suggest intelligence and malevolence

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova - Hence a 'qualified' no. Someone might have been stupid enough to send their astronauts to their certain deaths, but I doubt it.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova - Sure. It's also *possible* that Elvis is living in my basement. It's just not likely.

Comment: hmm, I wonder if this has any bearing on the theory of Neo's wireless head jack. Wouldn't it have gotten buggered too in the storm?